# Same ValueError using neuralintents library

Tags: python, json, artificial-intelligence, chatbot

I created a financial assistant chat bot  using python neuralintents module. But I am geeting the same error over and over again:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\micha\PycharmProjects\stock_price_alarm_bot\chat.py", line 112, in <module> assistant.train_model()
  File "C:\Users\micha\PycharmProjects\lib\site-packages\neuralintents\main.py", line 97, in train_model training = np.array(training)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (46,2) + inhomogeneous part.
```

I got this by watching this tutorial : https://youtu.be/Y47kjQvffPo?si=r1fOQRtZDlAX5wq8

Github repo : https://github.com/NeuralNine/neuralintents

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web
import mplfinance as mpf

import pickle
import sys
import  datetime as dt

portfolio = {'AAPL': 20, 'TSLA': 5, 'GS': 10}

with open('portfolio.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    portfolio = pickle.load(f)

def save_portfolio():
    with open('portfolio.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(portfolio, f)

def add_portfolio():
    ticker = input('Which stock are you adding: ')
    amount = int(input('How many shares are you adding: '))


    if ticker in portfolio.keys():
        portfolio[ticker] += amount
    else:
        portfolio[ticker] = amount

    save_portfolio()

def remove_portfolio():
    ticker = input('Which stock are you selling: ')
    amount = int(input('How many shares are you adding: '))


    if ticker in portfolio.keys():
        if amount <= portfolio[ticker]:
            portfolio[ticker] -= amount
            save_portfolio()
        else:
            print("You don't have enough shares!")

    else:
        print(f"You don't own any shares of {ticker}")


def show_portfolio():
    print('Your portfolio: ')
    for ticker in portfolio.keys():
        print(f'You own {portfolio[ticker] } shares of {ticker}')

def portfolio_worth():
    sum = 0
    for ticker in portfolio.keys():
        data = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo')
        price = data['Close'].iloc[-1]
        sum += price
    print(f'Your portfolio is worth {sum} USD')

def portfolio_gains():
    starting_date = input("Enter a date to compare to (YYYY-MM-DD): ")

    sum_now = 0
    sum_then = 0

    try:
        for ticker in portfolio.keys():
            data = web.DataReader(Ticker, 'yahoo')
            price_now  = data['Close'].iloc[-1]
            price_then = data.loc[data.index == starting_date]['Close'].values[0]
            sum_now += price_now
            sum_then+= price_then

        print(f'Relative Gains: {((sum_now - sum_then)/sum_then) * 100}%')
        print(f'Absolute Gains: {(sum_now - sum_then)} USD')
    except IndexError:
        print('There was no trading on this day!')

def plot_chart():
    ticker = input('Choose a ticker symbol: ')
    starting_string = input('Choose a starting date(DD/MM/YYYY): ')

    plt.style.use("dark_background")

    start = dt.datetime.strptime(starting_string, '%d/%m/%Y')
    end = dt.datetime.now()

    data = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)

    colors = mpf.make_marketcolors(up='#00ff00', down='#ff0000', wick='inherit', edge='inherit', volume='in')
    mpf_style  = mpf.make_mpf_style(base_mpf_style='nightclouds', marketcolors=colors)
    mpf.plot(data, type='candle', style=mpf_style, volume=True)

def bye():
    print('Goodbye')
    sys.exit(0)

mappings = {
'bye': bye,
'plot_chart': plot_chart,
    'add_portfolio': add_portfolio,
    'remove_portfolio': remove_portfolio,
    'show_portfolio': show_portfolio,
    'portfolio_worth': portfolio_worth,
    'portfolio_gains': portfolio_gains,

}

assistant = GenericAssistant('intents.json',mappings, 'financial_assistant_model')

assistant.train_model()
assistant.save_model()

while True:
    message = input("")
    assistant.request(message)
```

My json file:

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "tag": "greetings",
      "patterns": [
        "Hi",
        "How are you",
        "Is anyone there?",
        "Hello",
        "Good day",
        "Whats up",
        "I need help"
      ],
      "responses": [
        "Hi, how may I help you?",
        "Hi there, how can I help?"
      ]
    },
    {
      "tag": "bye",
      "patterns": [
        "Ok thanks",
        "See you later",
        "Goodbye",
        "I am Leaving",
        "Have a Good day",
        "Bye"
      ],
      "responses": [
        "Is there anything else I can help with?",
        "Talk to you later",
        "Goodbye!",
        "Hope I could help!"
      ]
    },
    {
      "tag": "plot_chart",
      "patterns": [
        "I want you to plot a stock price!",
        "Please plot a chart",
        "Plot a stock",
        "Plot a stock price",
        "Show me a stock price",
        "Candlestick chart",
        "Display stock graph"
      ],
      "responses": [
        "Plotting chart"
      ]
    },
    {
      "tag": "add_portfolio",
      "patterns": [
        "Add stock to my portfolio",
        "I want to add a stock",
        "Add a new stock",
        "Include a stock in my portfolio"
      ],
      "responses": [
        "Adding Stock"
      ]
    },
    {
      "tag": "remove_portfolio",
      "patterns": [
        "Remove stock from my portfolio",
        "I want to remove a stock",
        "Remove a stock",
        "Take a stock out of my portfolio"
      ],
      "responses": [
        "Removing Stock"
      ]
    },
    {
      "tag": "stock_price",
      "patterns": [
        "What's the current stock price?",
        "Tell me the stock price",
        "Get stock price",
        "How much is the stock right now?"
      ],
      "responses": [
        "Showing Stock Price"
      ]
    },
    {
      "tag": "show_portfolio",
      "patterns": [
        "Show me my portfolio",
        "Display my investments",
        "View my portfolio",
        "What stocks are in my portfolio?",
        "Portfolio overview"
      ],
      "responses": [
        "Showing Portfolio"
      ]
    },
    {
      "tag": "portfolio_worth",
      "patterns": [
        "What's my portfolio worth?",
        "Tell me the value of my portfolio",
        "Portfolio valuation",
        "How much is my investment portfolio worth?",
        "Current portfolio value"
      ],
      "responses": [
        "Portfolio Worth"
      ]
    },
    {
      "tag": "portfolio_gains",
      "patterns": [
        "Show me my portfolio gains",
        "Calculate portfolio gains",
        "Portfolio performance",
        "How well is my portfolio doing?"
      ],
      "responses": [
        "Portfolio Gains"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```